# Weird Behaviors of datetime(timezone) in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, timezone

In our rails 3.2 application, we have configured,

```
config.time_zone = 'London'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

And in postgresql also configured timezone as "Europe/London".

For the past one week, our application datetime field is not working properly with timezone.

For an example, If we create an reminder `start_date at 2015-08-18 10AM`. it creates `2015-08-18 10:00:00 in postgres database.

when displaying in template,

reminder `start date: 2015-08-18 10AM (2015-08-18 10:00:00 +0100 )`

`BUT,(not always) now frequently its showing UTC time.`

reminder `start date:  2015-08-18 9AM (2015-08-18 09:00:00 UTC )`

it could not be reproduced in development.

If we restart the unicorn server then it is not occurring for 4 hours.

anyone faced  this kind of  problem?

Comment: What is the exact code you use to print the dates in every case you mention? You'll see the differences. Time and Date with zones is an area you need to really be careful about in Rails.

Comment: In show, just extracting the AR object @reminder as, <℅= @reminder.start_date.strftime("%A %d-%m-%Y - %H:%M") %>.

Comment: I do not believe setting the date time in Rails the framework will actually do the same for your servers or necessarily your database.  When it comes to time I highly recommend doing everything around UTC time as much as possible and only converting at the very end.

Comment: sometimes config.time_zone = 'London' is taking 'UTC'. I agree your point.  Our application is very huge. so we are planning to change the timezzoneto UTC in future. but now the problem very annoying. timezone is not stable in all EC2 instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue, by adding `around filter` in `ApplicationController`.

```
around_filter :use_time_zone

private

def use_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone('London', &block)
end
```

So, whenever the default timezone changed to `UTC`, it will override and set as `BST`.